# Image of connected space under continuous function is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

> Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a continuous between metric spaces with $X$ being connected. Then $f[X] \subseteq Y$
> is also connected.

**Proof attempt:**

W.l.o.g. assume that $f$ is surjective. Suppose, for the sake of contradiction, there existed open sets $A, B\neq f[X]
, \varnothing $
with $f[X] = A \sqcup B$. Then $f^{-1}[A]$ and $f^{-1}[B]$ are neither $X$ nor $\varnothing$ (by surjectivity),
moreover they are
are open and clearly disjoint, so that
\begin{align*}
f^{-1}[A] \sqcup f^{-1}[B] = X
\end{align*}
which contradicts the fact that $X$ is connected.

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: It is correct. But which answer do you expect which would be more than a simple "yes"?

Comment: @PaulFrost How can he assume that $A$ and $B$ are open?  Is it not true that he can, at most, assume that they are separated?  Because, for example, if $X$ is closed then its continuous image must also be closed and cannot be the union of two open sets.

Comment: @AlanJenkins he is arguing by contradiction. Besides, the continuous image of a closed set need not be closed, and a closed set can be union of two open sets.

Comment: Regarding the proof attempt, this is of course correct, but I am not very happy with the sentence "$f^{-1}[A]$ and $f^{-1}[B]$ are neither $X$ nor $\emptyset$ by surjectivity": this follow by disjointness of $A$ and $B$ more than by surjectivity. Also, why do you say "assume $f$ surjective", if you then work with $f[X]$ and not directly with $Y$?

Comment: @arnett Surjectivity implies that they are not $\emptyset$.  That they are not $X$ is irrelevant for the following arguments. But the OP misses to require $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered in the comments. This is just to summarize what was said there.

1. You may of course assume that $f$ is surjective since $f: X \to f(X)$ is surjective. But then you should write $Y$ instead of $f(X)$. This is just a "stylistic" issue.
2. You forgot to assume that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Thus it is suffices to assume that $A, B \ne \emptyset$, it automatically follows that $A, B \ne Y = f(X)$.
3. The rest of your proof is correct. But again it suffices to say that $f^{-1}(A), f^{-1}(B) \ne  \emptyset$.

Comment: He uses the symbol of disjoint union for $A$ and $B$, so he did not forget anything about the intersection.

Comment: @arnett In this case the OP should have explained the meaning of $\sqcup$. I do not think it is a commonly accepted standard that it means disjoint union. Similarly the OP writes $f[X]$, other authors write $f(X)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I didn't know that the symbol for disjoint union wasn't commonly accepted, given that even wikipedia uses it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)

Comment: @PaulFrost also, $f(X)$ is ambiguous in cases where $f$ is a function that takes sets as an input, so in this sense $f[X]$ is a less error prone notation.

Comment: @Richard Notation is often non really standardized. In some cases this does not matter, for example everybody will understand both $f[X]$ and $f(X)$. But I recommend to explain symbols if there could be any doubt.

Comment: @Richard See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/mathematical-symbol-for-disjoint-set-union concerning disjoint union.